# Integrate layouts with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, devise, default

I'm using devise for user auth, however, I want the registration, login, and beta code enter pages to have a layout called 'beta' not the application (default) layout that the rest of the pages have.

I normally just change the layout in the controller but there aren't controllers with Devise. 
Is this not possible and I just have to change the application layout and have a specific layout for all other pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are controllers in devise and they are easy to customize.  Just do the following:

**app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout  "beta"
end
```

**/config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }
```

And do the same for registration and all other pages that you want to have this layout.

Comment: For regist it would be `class Users:RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` right?

And i'd add to the routes.rb `... :controllers => { ..., :registrations => "users/registrations" }`
Right?

Comment: Its good to note that you need to put the controller in **app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb**

Comment: Right. And anything else you want to customize would follow the same format as well.