# Using web-app-theme with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i've generated the devise views using `rails g devise:views` and then also followed the instructions to add the web-app-theme to `sign` but devise does not use that layout.

how you I change the devise layout to use web-app-theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new layout file, specifically for logging in.

```
- app
   - views
     - layouts
       application.html.erb
       - devise
         sessions.html.erb
```

So you have your application layout file, but you also have a folder called `devise`, and in it, is a layout file for devise sessions. Rails should automatically pick up this layout and use it since it is the same path and name as the view being displayed (views/devise/sessions) so it'll look for views/layouts/devise/sessions, and if it doesn't find it, it'll check if it's defined elsewhere.

**UPDATE**

Here's another potential solution I found on Stackoverflow.

[Integrate layouts with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647188/integrate-layouts-with-devise)

**UPDATE 2**

A third option is to do what the devise wiki says.
[How To: Create Custom Layouts](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts)

Comment: I am editing sessions.html.erb but I need to know what that should look like to work with wep-app-theme

Comment: Can you provide a link to your 'web-app-theme'? You'll have to take a look at some of the html and make your theme match the header and footer, and throw your 'yield' in there somewhere.

Comment: What I recommend is that you look at the html for a section of that theme you are interested in, and make your layout file match it, except you'll be adding a `yield` instead of the actual login box.